# Verifying email and hashed password always returns None when details are definitely in DB

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, hash, hashlib

I have a simple program to check if an email and hashed password are in a Postgres database (It's meant to be a cgi app, but because it fails, I'm testing it as a script first):

```
import cgi
import cgitb
import hashlib
import psycopg2
from dbconfig import *
cgitb.enable()
print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";

def checkPass():
    email = "person@gmail.com"
    password = "mypassword"
    password = hashlib.sha224(password.encode()).hexdigest()
    result = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM logins WHERE email=%s AND passhash=%s', (email, password))
    print result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    conn_string = "host=%s dbname=%s user=%s password=%s" % (host, database, dbuser, dbpassword)
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    checkPass()
```

This program always returns None on the print. The email and hashed password are definitely in the database though. I put them there with this:

```
email = "person@gmail.com"
allpass = "mypassword"
password = hashlib.sha224(allpass.encode()).hexdigest()
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO logins (email, passhash) VALUES (%s, %s);', (email, password))
conn.commit()
```

And checking the db shows there's that email and hashed password. So why doesn't the first program return something upon the SELECT statement? Are hashes not stored in the same way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: typo in your `cursor.execute` call? should that be: `% (email, password)`?

Comment: I don't think it matters since the second piece of code works without it, but trying it returns `ProgrammingError: column "person@gmail.com" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM logins WHERE email = "person@gmail.com....`

Comment: Ok, that last comment was just a problem in how I was passing it. Changing the query to use insecure escape characters etc still doesn't pull anything from the database - but entering that same query directly into the db does return the correct row. It's just in the python program that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out what was wrong. As it happens, cursor.execute() doesn't actually return anything. You have to use fetchone() for that.

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM logins WHERE email=%s AND passhash=%s;', (email, password))
result = cursor.fetchone()
print result
```

This prints a tuple of the correct results.